# Nested Javascript async functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, asynchronous

I am writing a Hearthstone pack opening simulator.  I am running into an issue when I try to open multiple packs.  When I open 1 pack I get an array of 5 cards.  When I open 2 packs I get 2 arrays of 10 cards.  I would like it to be 1 array of 10 cards.  I am thinking this is something to do with async functions or callbacks but not sure how to fix this.

```
var dataPromise;
var allCards;
var set;
var numberOfPacks;
var commons;
var rares;
var epics;
var legendarys;
var card;
var cardRob;
var pack = [];
var collection = [];
var pittyE;
var pittyL;
$(document).ready(function(){
    getCardData()
    .done(function(data){
        allCards = data;    
    });
    $('#submit').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
            filterByQuality();
            openPacks();
            console.log(collection);
        });
});
function getCardData() {
  if(!dataPromise){
    dataPromise = $.ajax({ // Store jQuery promise so that we can return it for subsequent calls ensuring only one AJAX request is made
      url: 'https://omgvamp-hearthstone-v1.p.mashape.com/cards?collectible=1',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Mashape-Authorization", "mXtnPm3ltOmshc9dQJjtVdKzfnhbp14UZncjsnfzwvp6uLiMwH");
      }
    });
  } 
  return dataPromise;
};
function filterByQuality(){
     set = document.getElementById('sets').value;
     commons = allCards[set].filter(function(common){
        return common.rarity == "Common"});
     rares = allCards[set].filter(function(rare){
        return rare.rarity == "Rare"});
     epics = allCards[set].filter(function(epic){
        return epic.rarity == "Epic"});
     legendarys = allCards[set].filter(function(legendary){
        return legendary.rarity == "Legendary"});

};
function getCard(){
    var x  = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1);
    if (x <= 96){
        card = legendarys[Math.floor(Math.random() * (legendarys.length))];
        pittyL = 0;
    }else if (x > 96 && x <= 420){
        card = epics[Math.floor(Math.random() * (epics.length))];
        pittyE = 0;
    }else if (x > 420 && x <= 2167){
        card = rares[Math.floor(Math.random() * (rares.length))];
    }else{
        card = commons[Math.floor(Math.random() * (commons.length))];
    }
    pack.push(card);
};
function getCardRob(){
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1);
    if (x <= 96){
        card = legendarys[Math.floor(Math.random() * (legendarys.length))];
        pittyL = 0;
    }else if (x > 96 && x <= 420){
        card = epics[Math.floor(Math.random() * (epics.length))];
        pittyE = 0;
    }else{
        card = rares[Math.floor(Math.random() * (rares.length))];
    }
    pack.push(card);
};
function getLegendary(){
    card = legendarys[Math.floor(Math.random() * (legendarys.length))];
    pack.push(card);
    pittyL = 0;
};
function getEpic(){
    card = epics[Math.floor(Math.random() * (epics.length))];
    pack.push(card);
    pittyE = 0;
};
function getPack(){
    pittyL ++;
    pittyE ++;
    if (pittyL == 40 && pittyE == 10){
        getLegendary();
        getEpic();
        getCard();
        getCard();
        getCard();
    } else if (pittyL = 40 && pittyE < 10){
        getLegendary();
        getCard();
        getCard();
        getCard();
        getCard();
    } else if (pittyL < 40 && pittyE == 10){
        getEpic();
        getCard();
        getCard();
        getCard();
        getCard();
    } else {
        getCardRob();
        getCard();
        getCard();
        getCard();
        getCard();
    }
    collection.push(pack);
};
function openPacks(){

    numberOfPacks = document.getElementById('nop').value;

    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfPacks; i++){
        getPack();
    }

};
```

Here is the html

```
​<html>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>Hearthstone Pack Simulator</h1>
                <form>
                <select name="sets" id="sets">
                    <option value="Classic">Classic</option>
                    <option value="Goblins vs Gnomes">Goblins vs Gnomes</option>
                    <option value="Journey to Un'Goro">Journey to Un'Goro</option>
                    <option value="Mean Streets of Gadgetzan">Mean Streets of Gadgetzan</option>
                        <option value="The Grand Tournament">The Grand Tournament</option>
                        <option value="Whispers of the Old Gods">Whispers of the Old Gods</option>
                </select>
                    <select name="no of packs" id="nop">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="20">20</option>
                        <option value="50">50</option>
                        <option value="100">100</option>
                    </select>
                <input type="submit" id="submit">
                </form>
        </header>
        <div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `getCard()` (or any of its varients) you are updating the global `pack`. You end up calling `getCard()` 10 times for two packs, so the same global `pack` gets updated with 10 total cards. `collection` is also global and gets updated with the same `pack` twice.

In order for this to work properly, you should create a new `pack` object each time you call `getPack()`.

Generally speaking, don't use global variables to manage this state. Instead, create a pack or collection object each time you call `getPack()`, `getCollection()`, etc and return that.

You only have one asynchronous function that gets all of the card data at the start. Asynchronicity isn't causing you any issues here.

```
function getCard() {
  let card = /* snip */
  return card;
}
function getPack() {
  let pack = [];
  pack.push(getCard());
  /* snip -- add more cards */
  return pack;
}
```

Comment: Okay got it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1) You have a typo mistake on `if (pittyL = 40`, should be `if (pittyL == 40)`.

2) I would recommend doing a method that gets the number of cards you want so you can do getCard(3); to get 3 cards and avoid calling same function a lot of times.

3) As for the pack issue, your pack variable is always the same and you always push cards to that variable, so if you open 100 packs, packs will have 500 cards. As for why you have 2 packs, its because you are doing `collection.push(pack);` every time you open a pack, so you are pushing to collection the same pack reference every time.

Answer (score 0):

You need separate pack array for each getPack() call.

Please, for your pleasure rewrite this in objects, also consider [scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

Once you use objects and correct scope, it should be allright.

```
var variable_passed_to_function;
variable_passed_to_function = 'foo';

console.log( variable_from_outside_of_function );

function myFunction( variable_from_outside_of_function ) {
    let variable_for_only_inside_of_function;
    variable_for_only_inside_of_function = 'bar';
    console.log( variable_from_outside_of_function );
    console.log( variable_for_only_inside_of_function );
    variable_from_outside_of_function = 'baz';
    console.log( variable_from_outside_of_function );
    console.log( variable_for_only_inside_of_function );
    return 'this can be also usable';
}

another_variable = myFunction( variable_passed_to_function );

console.log( another_variable );
console.log( variable_passed_to_function );
console.log( variable_for_only_inside_of_function );
```